Equally distribute different amounts of rows in neighbouring columns in a table
I want to make a table with several columns that have different amounts of rows while distributing the rows equally over the whole vertical space available. For example three rows take up 33% each and four 25% accordingly. In the provided example I made a workaround that shows the distribution I need but has too much vertical empty space because of the empty rows (look at the output image). How can I achieve this more cleanly and efficiently?
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    &\\
    Text& Text \\
    &\\
    &\\
    &\\
    & Text  \\
    &\\
    Text &\\
    &\\
    & Text \\
    &\\
    &\\
    &\\
    Text & Text  \\
    &\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}



Not sure to have completely understood your problem, but maybe this could help.
I created a box with the highest table, I calculated its height and use it to set the height of the rows of the other table as "height of the highest/number of rows of the current table".
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\newlength{\myheight}

\begin{document}
\newsavebox{\highesttab}
\savebox{\highesttab}%
    {\begin{tblr}{}
        Text\\
        Text\\
        Text\\
        Text
    \end{tblr}}
\settototalheight\myheight{\usebox{\highesttab}}

\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,rowsep=0pt,colsep=0pt}
    \begin{tblr}{
        rows={ht={\myheight/3}},
        rowsep=0pt,
        }
    Text\\
    Text\\
    Text
    \end{tblr}
    &
    \usebox{\highesttab}\\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}



This certainly does come closer to what I consider "aesthetically pleasing" although the offset in the first and last rows is a little bit flawed. As soon as I have the time I'll try to adjust some values to fix that, thanks.

@Mathician Do you want the first and the last left "Text" aligned with the first and last right "Text"?

Exactly.
I tried shifting the rows with changing values of inner specifications I found in the documentation (p. 26) but don't know how to apply those to individual lines. Apart from that this approach of mine doesn't seem clean though.
